# can't understand derviatives from searching all over the internet

Tags: calculus, derivatives, reference-request

I have tried to follow a lot of tutorials out there for explaining derviatives and show (understandable)examples but i couldn't understand any. Can anyone link me a useful and easy to follow tutorial or explain derviatives  for me?

Comment: Become friends with a textbook :)

Comment: Have you tried Khan Academy?

Comment: @John Doe  yes but it seems like they are over complicating it.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 i live in a country that does speak a different language than my original one so that's why i can't find an english book to understand from.

Comment: @Frankoo where do you live and what's your original language? Do you have any mathematical background? What have you studied of limits?

Comment: @Célio Augusto  i live in albania my original language is arabic and yes i have some mathematical background but they aren't that good and i didn't study limits.

Comment: Well, if you didn't sduty limits, it's no wonder you can't understand derivatives, since a derivative is a limite. First you must study limits.

Comment: @Célio Augusto thank you , Is there are any other thing i need to know beside limits?

Comment: @Frankoon You must understand the concept of function, and be familiarized with the basic functions (trig, polynomials, exponential, etc. Take a look on the Khan Academy pre-calculus course.

Comment: "Derivatives" is typical of a mathematical concept that is at the crossroad of many concepts. As often, looking at the history of their discovery is valuable : they were discovered by Newton, rising from celestial mechanics (cinematics branch), as instantaneous speeds of objects of the Solar system. Considering derivatives as speeds is one of the keys to their understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend watching 3blue1brown's series on calculus. If you're having trouble grasping the intuition behind derivatives, then his animation style definitely helps out. He has a clear geometric representations on different topics. Just remember that although his videos are very useful for intuition, it's more qualitative than quantative. Be sure to explore the topics even further on your own and do practice questions.

Comment: don't forget to "pause and ponder"

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2PpRnFqnqY

Khan Academy is a great resource if you want to learn math online. It also has a wide selection of calculus tutorials that are all narrated and explained very well.

I will try to explain what a derivative is in a nutshell: it is the slope of a line at a point. For example, the derivative of the function $f(x) = x^2$ is $f'(x) = 2x$. (the apostrophe, or 'prime' is just convention for derivatives.) You will notice that for $x = 1$, the slope of the tangent line is $2x$ or $2(1)$. (You will also have to change the y intercept). Observe the image:

[parabola image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHesw.png)

Comment: it also confused me. i guess i need to learn limits first and pre calculus  but thank you for your effort :)

Comment: (+1) Khan Academy is a great resource. I also recommend [Paul's Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/) for everything between algebra to calc 3 and differential equations. As someone who has done a substantial bit of self-teaching, Paul's math notes are a really good resource.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a very simple one.

lets say you want to find out the derivative of
 $$3x^2$$

You bring down the exponent which is 2 and multiply it by 3, just like this.

2*3x

and then you subtract that exponent by 1.

so it should look like this: $n*(3x^{n-1})$

therefore the answer would be 6x. There's other rules and etc, however this is just a basic idea and concept of it.